# Compile latex from php: "Error: Invalid XRef stream header"

Tags: php, latex, pdflatex, xelatex

I have been trying to compile latex from php. I got the help from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0NEGoeil64). However, I keep getting this error.

> > Error: Invalid XRef stream header Error: Invalid XRef stream header pdf.worker.js:232:5
> >     XRef_readXRef@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:3708:13
> >     XRef_parse@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:3296:23
> >     PDFDocument_setup@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:2469:7
> >     PDFDocument_parse@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:2350:7
> >     ensureHelper@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1971:22
> >     NetworkPdfManager_ensure/<@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1985:7
> >     NetworkPdfManager_ensure@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1965:1
> >     BasePdfManager_ensureDoc@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1832:14
> >     loadDocument/

Note: I have installed texlive in ubuntu so I can use pdftex. 
      xelatex is also installed.

Web server content:
 small latex file  contained **"latex_template.php"**  and the
 **index.php** contains the following php script.

```
   ob_start();
 include 'latex_template.php';
 $outputData .=ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();

 $texFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'test');

 $base = basename($texFile);

 rename($texFile, $texFile.".tex");
 $texFile .= ".tex";
 file_put_contents($texFile,  $outputData);
 chdir(dirname(realpath($texFile)));

 $console = shell_exec("xelatex {$base}" );
 //$console = system("xelatex {$base}" );

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
$pdf = dirname(realpath($console)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$base.".pdf";

readfile($pdf);
```

Note: Manual execution xelatex: log file:
 [image]

Comment: I suggest you check manually: is a pdf file generated? Most likely not. Does a manual execution of that `xelatex` call succeed? Maybe. THe difference _could_ be file permissions...

Comment: Hi @arkascha , I execute " xelatex hello.tex " I have the above log file. I have to press two time. the pdf is generate. Same with pdftex

Comment: All files have the following permission: -rw-rw-r-- 1

Comment: With "manually" I referred to executing that command on the command line, obviously.